# Modern replacement for cbDSMixer?

Tags: delphi, directshow, delphi-xe

I was working on updating a D6 media library to XE over the weekend.  I got it working with a surprisingly low number of Unicode-related errors, but there are a few things I'd like to try to improve.

Unfortunately, the core of the player is cbDSMixer, which isn't all that flexible, and the author has stated that ["Now with a family of wife and 2 kids I can't find the needed time to play around doing extra development so all those components are pretty old by now and mostly deprecated."](http://www.carlosb.com/work.html)  So I wonder if there are any alternatives.

So does anyone know of an alternate media player library that will work properly under XE, and support the same or most of the same mixing and effects functionality as cbDSMixer?

Comment: Why not ask the developer if you can take over on it?

Comment: @Warren: Because I don't understand the code well enough to maintain it and take responsibility for it.  Trace into it hunting down a specific bug, maybe.  I'm pretty good at that.  But understanding the big picture and the overall implementation is different.

Comment: Seeing you're 34K delphi guy on StackOverflow means I think you would be able to do anything you wanted to do.  :-)

Comment: @Warren: Yeah, probably, if I dedicate enough time and effort to figuring it out.  But I don't want to do that; that's why I'm asking about prebuilt libraries. :P

Comment: @Mason, what exactly does cbDSMixer do ?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the [Audio Component Suite](http://wiki.freepascal.org/ACS) from Andrei Borovsky. Not sure how much this lib is maintained, but it looks very promising (cross platform apparently, which may become even more important in the future)

Comment: Looks interesting, but I can't use it since it's licensed LGPL and I'm looking for something I can statically link into the project.

Comment: @Mason, sorry, overlooked the LGPL. When I played with the ACS I actually used the original version from http://www.mtu-net.ru/aborovsky/acs/. But since this one seems to be no longer maintained, maybe not the way to go.